# Interactions between camera and procedural terrain

Tags: c#, collision-detection, xna-4.0

**QUESTION REWORKED**

I need to update every frame camera position along a surface with hills and drops.
In this picture you can see a particle of the surface terrain (just one triangle) and a sphere representing the camera. It is set in a certain point of the surface and has a velocity in the XZ plane.

What I want to do is check the plane sloping and modify the velocity in order to move smoothly on the surface without "entering" in it like if it was a ladder

[image]

How should I proceed? I can easily ccess informations like vertex coordinates, surface normale (in that particular triangle) and I think whatever you thinkcould be of help but since I have difficulties in painting on a paper what should I expect I don't know how to approach this problem.

Can someone help me?

Comment: My advice: Start drawing pictures to post here, if you want your question answered. It may be obvious to you what you're doing, but it's not particularly obvious to others, even with a written explanation.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: You have to check the next surface height and move the camera up or down accordingly, I'd say.

Comment: You want to interpolate between heights?  (hint: that's the short version of the answer.)

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch I guess this is the right terminology! Unfortunately I'm damn new to this. Could you please help me with a complete (dummy proof) answer?

Comment: Are you essentially asking how to ensure the camera doesn't intersect terrain, or doesn't come within some distance of it?

Comment: well, actually that doesn't intersect the terrain

Comment: @anko reading again my comment, I think I should say that I aim that the camera should not pass thought the terrain surface when falling. And, when moving on the surface should follow the planes formed with the vertexes